# DHCP lease expiry shows as "0 seconds" on TP-Link router

Tags: dhcp-server

A client who runs a small café sometimes has occasional trouble with new people logging on so I've volunteered to monitor their router for a while. I've noticed that when an entry reaches it's expiry, it's not removed from the DHCP list and says "Expires in 0 seconds". I kind of expected the entries to be removed from the DHCP table when they expired but is it possible/feasible that the DHCP server "hangs on" to expired leases just in case the device comes back? But it runs out of DHCP addresses, it would start re-using these expired entries?

I know that DHCP prefers to give the same IP address back to the same client if it can so wondered if this was part of that mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

I would try a firmware upgrade, as when expired the entry should be erased. If that don't fix the problem try a new router please.

The router/dhcp got a mechanism before the expiration to renew the bail in case the device was not there, but that mechanism happen before te expiration.

> The renewal process occurs when a client already has a lease, and
>   needs to renew that lease with the server. To ensure that addresses
>   are not left in an assigned state when they are no longer needed, the
>   DHCP server places an administrator-defined time limit, known as a
>   lease duration, on the address assignment. Halfway through the lease
>   period, the DHCP client requests a lease renewal, and the DHCP server
>   extends the lease. If a computer stops using its assigned IP address
>   (for example, if a computer is moved to another network segment or is
>   removed), the lease expires and the address becomes available for
>   reassignment. The renewal process occurs as follows: The client sends
>   a request to the DHCP server, asking for a renewal and extension of
>   its current address lease. The client sends a directed request to the
>   DHCP server, with a maximum of three retries at 4, 8, and 16 seconds.
>   If the DHCP server can be located, it typically sends a DHCP
>   acknowledgment message to the client. This renews the lease. If the
>   client is unable to communicate with its original DHCP server, the
>   client waits until 87.5 percent of its lease time elapses. Then the
>   client enters a rebinding state, broadcasting (with a maximum of three
>   retries at 4, 8, and 16 seconds) a DHCPDiscover message to any
>   available DHCP server to update its current IP address lease. If a
>   server responds with a DHCPOffer message to update the client's
>   current lease, the client renews its lease based on the offering
>   server and continues operation. If the lease expires and no server has
>   been contacted, the client must immediately discontinue using its
>   leased IP address. The client then proceeds to follow the same process
>   used during its initial startup to obtain a new IP address lease.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958919.aspx

nb, DHCP reservation should be displayed as n/a / static in the same windows

Comment: Unfortunately the firmware is already up to date. I think the basic problem is this particular router isn't up to the job of handling multiple connections although it's supposed to be able to handle 32 connections. It doesn't seem to be releasing them for whatever reason. I've disabled the Wi-Fi and stuck in a Ubiquiti UAP-AC for a week to isolate the fault

Comment: This router is also showing DHCP entries of 49710 days, 6 hours and 28 minutes and 15 seconds. This piqued the programmer in me and it turns out that the lease time is stored in seconds - 49710*24*60*60+6*60*60++28*60+15 = 4,294,967,295 = 0xFFFFFFFF. Definitely another magic number - I'm guessing the DHCP server uses 0 and -1 for special values but the display code doesn't handle them correctly. I guess it should say something like "Expired" and "Unknown" respectively

Comment: @RobNicholson I would try another router as the firmware is already at the last version, something buggy in the router

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Fortunately, not an expensive throwaway